# From Parent window close Child window which is opened by form submit with target="_blank"

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms, dom

My web application is loaded in a browser window. I have to open a new tab (child window) when I submit a Form on the parent page.

I am using a `<form .../>` tag with `target='_blank'` *attribute* which is opening a new browser tab when I do form submit while clicking button/link. Also I am passing some values through  controls inside the form so that I can get and use the same values in the target page. 
Cool, everything good.

Now what I wanted to do is, I need to close the new tab (child window) which is opened by form submit based on some condition at Parent window.

Feel free to share your thoughts could help me in some way.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this.

(NOTE: Here it will not work so open my below codepen link)

Codepen link: [Click me](https://codepen.io/bhavik103/pen/rNNbPKv)

```js
var myWindow1;
var myWindow2;

function openWin1() {
  myWindow1 = window.open("", "myWindow1", "width=500,height=100");
  myWindow1.document.write("<p>This is 'myWindow1'</p>");
}

function closeWin1() {
  myWindow1.close();
}

function openWin2() {
  myWindow2 = window.open("", "myWindow2", "width=200,height=100");
  myWindow2.document.write("<p>This is 'myWindow2'</p>");
}

function closeWin2() {
  myWindow2.close();
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<button onclick="openWin1()">Open "myWindow1"</button>
<button onclick="closeWin1()">Close "myWindow1"</button>

<button onclick="openWin2()">Open "myWindow2"</button>
<button onclick="closeWin2()">Close "myWindow2"</button>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Bhavik Kalariya,
Thanks for your response. Yes, it will work with 'window.open' but unfortunately for some reason i should use <form target="_blank" method="post"..> ....</form>. So is there any idea how can we achieve the same for this case?